# Completely unhide view prior to UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am using UIView.animateWithDuration to slide in a view upon tap recognition. This is working fine except, for the very first time, the view is unhidden slightly late and it suddenly appears mid-way through the animation. Subsequent show/hide operations do not have this issue.

I am implementing this as follows

```
    textBlurBackground.hidden = false
    descriptionOutlet.hidden = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {
        self.textBlurBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        self.descriptionOutlet.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        }, completion: nil)
```

so it seems like, even though I'm setting the "hidden" property first (on the first two lines) this is somehow delayed and only executed while the animation is already running. Note that this only happens the first time when the view is created; subsequent show/hide operations work fine (the views are completely unhidden prior to the animation).

I notice there is a "completion" hook - is there something equivalent for a preparation phase? I.e. don't start the animation until view is fully unhidden.

Comment: Perhaps implement an NSTimer to delay it from starting within the first 3 seconds. Dirty way of doing it but should allow for everything to load up first.

Comment: Are you doing other stuff when you are performing the animation? (Like loading data from cache).

Comment: In which method have you put this code?

Comment: Try using my [delay function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994) to supply a short delay that wraps the `animate` call. This will give the `hidden` change time to take effect visibly. `delay(0.1) {UIView.animateWithDuration...}`

Comment: @Rufel This code is in a tap handling outlet ```@IBAction func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)```

@matt I'll also try out the delay function and see if that can work around it.

Comment: In the code you posted, the animation call had the parameter delay:.  Just set that to 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the timing advice (and running things slowly) in the comments I could figure out that, in this case, it was not a timing issue but, rather, the dimensions of the views were somehow incorrect when the view was first loaded. E.g. I have in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    textBlurBackground.hidden = true
    descriptionOutlet.hidden = true
    descriptionOutlet.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-textBlurBackground.bounds.width, 0)
    textBlurBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-textBlurBackground.bounds.width, 0)
}
```

the `textBlurBackground.bounds.width` is incorrect at that point; that code does not fully move those views off the screen by the negative width of the textBlueBackground view. But, once the view is loaded, subsequent show/hide operations do work correctly as it can then get the right size for the view.

Thus it seems this is an issue with auto-layout sizing where "textBlurBackground.bounds.width" is not correct upon initial view loading. Which is odd because it does not change size so I may need to specify some more constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A view may take a few milliseconds to appear for the first time because it has to be rendered/drawn on screen, mostly if this view contains a lot of subviews.  Are you instantiating that view in that same `handleTap` function?  You should be instantiating the view either in the `viewDidLoad` method of your UIViewController, or in the `init` of your UIView.  Set hidden what needs to be hidden right after instantiating the view.  Next, in the `handleTap`, unhide them and do the animation like posted above.